# Try-Catch: Is it OK to leave applications with handled exceptions?

Tags: android, exception, android-edittext

I am still fairly new to programming, so there are some things I learn from observing but do not fully understand. The Try-Catch is one of these things. From what I have researched, the try statement allows me to define a block of code to be tested for errors, and the catch statement allows me to define a block of code to be executed if an error occurs in the try block.

I get that. And I have tried to use Try-Catch in situations where I was receiving exception errors that crashed my applications. The Try-Catch seemed to prevent (stop) the crashing. But here is my question, is it OK to have an application that constantly catches an exception error?

For example, I am working with EditText widget. I want the input values for the EditText to represent currency, so I applied android:inputType="numberDecimal". The issue I learned with this is that this attribute allows any number of values after the decimal. This is when I came up with an idea of updating the EditText programmically with the proper format, using something like DecimalFormat.

I am not posting my entire code, but here is the piece that I am curious about.

```
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

        if (etBill.getText().toString() != null && 
                etBill.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
            try {
                doubleBill = Double.parseDouble(etBill.getText().toString());
                strFormatted = format.format(doubleBill);
                Log.d(TAG, "unformatted(" + doubleBill + ")" + 
                        " // formatted(" + strFormatted + ")");

                //etBill.setText("$" + strFormatted, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                etBill.setText("$" + strFormatted);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                Log.e(TAG, "FloatingPointParser.parseDouble error");
            }
        } else {
            // values in editText were deleted; hardcode value
            doubleBill = 0.0;
            strFormatted = format.format(doubleBill);
        }

    }
```

And here is the exception error I catch every single time I input a value into my EditText widget.

[image]

So my question is, is the Try-Catch a method for me to correct my errors? Is it OK to catch exception errors, such as this NumberFormapException through the life of an application running? Am I using this right? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NumberFormatException` is a runtime exception and you are catching it correctly. However, instead of just printing something to let you know you have caught it, you should either handle it by re-running through your code or pass the exception up the stack. For example, if a user inputs a number and then this exception is caught, you could prompt them to re-enter a new number. If the number that is throwing this exception is not provided by a user, but by your code, then it indicates you have a logic error somewhere and should fix that to prevent this exception from being thrown in the first place.

Comment: Prompt the user with like a Toast or something like that?

Comment: Exactly, a toast or anything of that nature. It's a little hard to point you in the exactly correct direction without knowing the context in which this code is used.

Comment: O, I see. I like that idea, thank you csmckelvey! I am going to flag your response as the answer. I will do that.

Answer (score 2):

In general the exception mechanism should be used for exceptional circumstances - something that usually shouldn't happen. If you have an exception that's being thrown every time you enter a value, that's sort of abusing the mechanism. Usually there's a better way that doesn't involve exceptions. In some cases though, the exception mechanism is the cleanest way of dealing with the situation.

Here's a quote from *Effective Java: Programming Language Guide* by Josh Bloch:

"Use exceptions only for exceptional conditions. That is, do not use exceptions for control flow, such as catching NoSuchElementException when calling Iterator.next() instead of first checking Iterator.hasNext()."

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I actually just learned this by trying to throw. The application did not respond too well, so very good point.

Answer (score 2):

Exception handling is not only an art but the subject of much discussion/debate. I will try to address the broader points without incurring anyone's wrath.

There are two kinds of exceptions--fault exceptions and contingency exceptions. Fault exceptions are unrecoverable like being unable to connect to a web service that is supposed to be there for your app to function. You log those in your `catch` block and rethrow to let them bubble to some fault handler. Contingency exceptions are what you described with the number format issue--stuff you can recover from. In this case, you handle things completely in the `catch` block. You allow the app to recover by prompting for a new input, for example.

By the way, none of that is my own. That strategy comes from [Barry Ruzek](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/entarch/effective-exceptions-092345.html).

Then there is the issue where people dislike using exceptions for flow control--for good reason. In your case, that would mean using a regular expression in an `if` statement, for example, to test number format rather than using a potential exception-generating operation. You generally don't want to use exceptions for normal control flow, but you also need to be careful not to let ideology trump a simple solution. There is a balance you will learn with experience.

So you should recover from the exception in your `catch` block. Or use a different non-exceptional mechanism entirely to manage control flow.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Aye, this does help. Just took me to school, thanks! I will try to come up with something.

Comment: Teaching is something I do, so happy to provide a bit of a lesson. Just make sure no one takes your lunch money.

Answer (score 1):

Using Try catch in programing  is fair enough. But handling errors is different issue. Try catch is just to way catch erronious conditions which can occur in ur program but u may wish to catch it or leave its up to you. Simple example is age is not allowed as floating point number but height is allowed both floating point and decimal number.